# How can I show that if $L \neq 0$, then $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ may not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

If $c \in R$ and $f : R \to R$ be so that $\lim_{x \to c} (f(x))^2 = L$, how can I show that if $L \neq 0$, then $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ may not exist?

Comment: Hint: try to think of a function $f$ whose codomain is $\{±1\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x)=\text{sgn} (x)$, $f(x)f(x)=1$ for all $x\neq 0$. So $(f(x))^2\to1 $as $x\to 0$. But $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ not exist

Comment: @dxiv Ok thanks in advice

Comment: I would add as follows [Take $f(x)=\text{sgn} (x)$, and extend it with $f(0)\in \{-1,1\}$ (choose arbitrarily), then $f(x)f(x)=1$ for all $x$. So $(f(x))^2\to1 $as $x\to 0$. But $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ not exist] because, for the MO, $dom(f)=\mathbb{R}$.